# Powershell iteration to delete contacts

Tags: .net, powershell, iteration, powershell-2.0

I would like to make an iteration which automatically deletes all contacts from Outlook.

This first row makes the collection:

```
$olSession = (New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application).Session
$olSession.Logon('Outlook')
$contactsFolder = 10
$elemek = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Items
```

I can delete one item, if I know the name:

```
 $deleteone = $elemek | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq "Your Name"}
 $deleteone.Delete()
```

But I would like to delete all contacts automatically, so I get the number of elements in `$elemek` with  `$elemek.Count`.

I don't know how to get the value of the array "dynamically":

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $elemek.Count; $i++)
{
    # The following line is not working
    $elemek.Count[0].Delete()
}
```

Could you help me to fix the iteration?

Thank you.

***Addition:***

If i run this:

```
 $elemek | Format-Table FullName,MobileTelephoneNumber,Email1Address
```

I got this:

```
FullName      MobileTelephoneNumber       Email1Address
--------      ---------------------       -------------
Morgan Freeman                            /o=Mydomain/ou=Exchange Administrativ...                            
Johny English                             /o=Mydomain/ou=Exchange Administrativ...
```

**So i really need to got FullName from $elemek and use in the script block of the for itaration.**

Comment: `$elemek |%{$_.delete()}`  . % is an alias of foreach

Comment: I tried with foreach, but something wrong with foreach because every time i run the script only the half of the contacts deleted. Run again...and half again..just halves...

Comment: Im sorry, but im not sure how...for ($i=0; $i -le $elemek.Count; $i++) {$elemek |%{$_.delete()} } 
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The operation failed."

Comment: don't put it in the for loop. Just this PS> $elemek | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq "Your Name"}| %{$_.delete()}

Comment: ? I need to make it automatically - dinamically.. My main problem is how to  get "Your Name" like "$elemek.Count[0].Delete()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ForEach-Object`, but preread content of `$elemek` before deleting:

```powershell
@($elemek)|ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

Comment: "Sometimes" the script stop before the end. Any idea whats the problem, how to investigate what causing?

Comment: @holian Does it produce any error/warning? Does next statement in the script executes or not?

Answer (score 0):

the exception could be raised if $elemk contains null value, try this :
...

```
$ErrorActionPreference="stop"
 $elemek = $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Items 
try{

    $elemk |%{ if ($_) { $_.delete() } }
}
catch{
"error occured :" 
$_
}
```

Comment: It raised as you tought...but its working as foreach...If i have 10 contacts and run this than 5 contacts left... I don't understand why halves...why not delete all of the contacts..

Comment: The script stopping after the last "}"